# Proof that negative binomial distribution is a distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, alternative-proof

In my textbook, a clear proof that the **Geometric Distribution** is a distribution function is given, namely

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pr(X=n)=p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{n-1} = \frac{p}{1-(1-p))}=1.$$

Then the textbook introduces the **Negative Binomial Distribution**; it gives a fairly clear explanation for why the PMF of a Negative Binomial random variable $N$ with parameter $r$ is

$$p\binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{n-r} $$

But to show

$$\sum_{n=r}^{\infty} \Pr(N=n)=\sum_{n=r}^{\infty}\binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{n-r}=1$$

the textbook gives (in my opinion) a wordy and informal argument that is nowhere near as clear.

What is a straightforward algebraic way to prove the above statement; that the Negative Binomial is a distribution function? I also looked at a different probability textbook, plus [wolfram.com's definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialDistribution.html)  before asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's evident that $\Bbb{P}(N=n)\ge 0$ for $n\ge r$. So you have to prove that $\sum_{n\ge r}\Bbb{P}(N=n)=1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge r}\Bbb{P}(N=n)&=\sum_{n\ge r} \binom {n-1} {r-1} p^r \left({1-p}\right)^{n-r}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge r} \binom {n-1} {n-r} p^r \left({1-p}\right)^{n-r}\;\;\quad\quad\text{(symmetry})\\
&=p^r\sum_{j\ge 0} \binom {r+j-1} {j} \left({1-p}\right)^{j}\qquad\text{(substituting }j=n-r)\\
&=p^r\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j \binom{-r}{j}\left({1-p}\right)^{j}\qquad\text{(identity}\tbinom{j+r-1}{j}=(-1)^j \tbinom{-r}{j})\\
&=p^r\sum_{j\ge 0} \binom{-r}{j}\left({p-1}\right)^{j}\\
&=p^r\left(1+(p-1)\right)^{-r} \qquad\qquad\qquad\text{(binomial theorem) }\\
&=1
\end{align}
$$
using the identity
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{j+r-1}{j}&=\frac{(j+r-1)(j+r-2) \cdots r}{j!}\\
&=(-1)^j \frac{(-r-(j-1))(-r-(j-2)) \cdots (-r)}{j!} \\&=(-1)^j \frac{(-r)(-r-1) \cdots (-r-(j-1))}{j!} \\&=(-1)^j \binom{-r}{j}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can show this directly with generating functions: $$\left({z\over 1-z}\right)^r=\left( \sum_{\alpha\geq 1} z^\alpha \right)^r
=\sum_{\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_r \geq 1} z^{\alpha_1+\cdots +\alpha_r}=\sum_{n\geq r} {n-1\choose r-1} z^n.$$ 
The last equation follows from ["stars and bars"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)
 which gives you the number of compositions of $n$ in $r$ pieces. 
Now substitute in $z=1-p$ to get the result.

Comment: In my Probability theory undergrad course, and to the extent of my math curriculum so far, we have yet to cover generating functions. Exam is tomorrow, so I'll look at this approach later.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the negative binomial probabilities sum to $1$ is a consequence of the following result (set $x:=1-p$ and rearrange):

**Claim:** If $|x|<1$ then for each $r=1,2,\ldots$ $$\sum_{n=r}^\infty {n-1\choose r-1}x^{n-r}=(1-x)^{-r}.\tag1$$

**Proof:** Use induction on $r$. For the base case $r=1$, the claim is that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=(1-x)^{-1}$ when $|x|<1$, which follows from the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Now suppose (1) holds for $r$. The LHS of (1) is a power series in $x$, with radius of convergence $1$ (by the ratio test), so [it can be differentiated term by term](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484250/215011) to obtain
$$
\sum_{n=r}^\infty{n-1\choose r-1}(n-r)x^{n-r-1}=r(1-x)^{-r-1},\tag2
$$
valid whenever $|x|<1$. The sum on the LHS of (2) can be started at $n=r+1$, since $n=r$ contributes nothing. Rewrite (2) using the identity $(n-r){n-1\choose r-1}=r{n-1\choose r}$, then divide through by $r$. This yields
$$\sum_{n=r+1}^\infty{n-1\choose (r+1)-1}x^{n-(r+1)}=(1-x)^{-(r+1)},\tag3$$
which establishes (1) for $r+1$.