# Why the differentiation of $e^x$ is $e^x?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x=e^x$$
Please explain simply as I haven't studied the first principle of differentiation yet, but I know the basics of differentiation.

Comment: how is $e^x$ defined?

Comment: If you don't have the definition of derivative, how do you know the basics of differentiation? It's hard to know how to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe he wants an *intuitive* answer, just to grasp the meaning behind this basic result.

Comment: Try this then. Imagine a function $f$ such that $df/dx = f$. What does the graph look like? Try to sketch it out. You'll (hopefully) convince yourself it has to look like an exponential function $f(x) = Ca^x$. To narrow to why $a = e$, we need to do a bit more technical work.

Comment: This really needs some editing to improve the question, but I voted to leave it open because it has attracted some good answers which have been well supported by votes, and which do attempt in different ways, to address elementary understandings related to the exponential function and its derivative.

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at the series representation of $e^x$ which is
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\dots$$
Taking derivative of this gives
$$\left(e^x\right)'=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)'=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\dots\right)'$$
$$=1'+x'+\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)'+\left(\frac{x^3}{6}\right)'+\left(\frac{x^4}{24}\right)'+\left(\frac{x^5}{120}\right)'+\dots$$
$$\implies (e^x)'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)'$$Then, differentiating term by term gives us
$$(e^x)'=0+1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots$$
$$=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\dots$$
$$=e^x$$
$$\implies \frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

Comment: You have to justify the interchange of limit operations here. A priori, it is not clear at all that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)$ is equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\right)$.

Comment: @Math1000: I agree that it should be mentioned for completeness that any power series can be differentiated (or integrated) term by term in the interior of the domain of convergence. See for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484250/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-a-power-series-can-be-differentiated-term-by-term

Answer (score 13):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}e^x &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots \right)\\
&=0+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{2x}{2!}+\frac{3x^2}{3!}+\dots\\
&=0+1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots\\
&=0 + e^x\\
&=e^x
\end{align}

Comment: Perhaps you could merge your answers?

Answer (score 11):

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n$$

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}e^x &= \frac{d}{dx}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{d}{dx}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n-1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{-1}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n\\
&=1\cdot e^x\\
&=e^x
\end{align}

Comment: I think you need to justifying switching the limit and the differentiation.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}e^x\left(\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right)=e^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=e^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1+h-1+o(h)}{h}$$$$=e^x\lim_{h\to 0}\left(1+\underbrace{\frac{o(h)}{h}}_{\to 0}\right)=e^x$$

Comment: This answer is logically circular. The only way you get the power series approximation for $e^h$ is to know the derivative.

Comment: not if $e^x$ is defined via a power series expansion.

Comment: Historically, $e^x$ was defined at first as infinite power series.

Answer (score 4):

**Visual Representation of the Slope of $e^x$**

[image: graph]

We can see that the slope is equal to $y$ at any point $(x, y)$.

**Proof by Implicit Differentiation**

First note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac{1}{x} $$
And
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=\frac{d}{dg(x)}f(g(x))\frac{d}{dx}g(x) $$
So now we have
$$ f(x)=e^x $$
$$ \ln f(x)=\ln e^x $$
$$ \ln f(x)=x $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x $$
$$ \frac{1}{f(x)}\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)=1 $$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

Answer (score 3):

solving the equation $\frac{df}{dx}=f$ we get $$\frac{df}{f}=dx$$ and we obtain $$\ln|f|=x+C$$ from here we get $$f(x)=e^{x+C}$$ with $f(0)=1$ we get $$f(x)=e^x$$

Comment: Nice. I would also finally add that the boundary condition is $f(0)=0,$ otherwise $e^x$ is not uniquely defined!

Comment: @alexqwx I think you mean $f(0)=1$. Of course, any function in the form $f(x)=Ae^x$ is equal to it's derivative, $e^x$ is just a canonical example.

Comment: Yep- I do. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Note that $\ln|f(x)|=x+C$ does NOT yield $f(x)=e^{x+C}$ but $f(x)=\pm e^{x+C}$.

Comment: This is a circular argument.

Comment: This proves that if there is a solution to f’=f then it must look like Ce^x, but leaves open the question of whether or not a solution exists.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y = e^x$:

$$\begin{align*}
x &= \ln y\\
\frac{dx}{dy} &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(y+h)-\ln y}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{y}\right)^\frac1h\\
&=\ln\lim_{h\to0}\left(1+\frac{h}{y}\right)^{\frac yh\cdot \frac1y}\\
&= \ln \left(e^\frac1y\right)\\
&= \frac1y\\
&= \frac1{e^x}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= e^x
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is the only attempt that's not a circular reasoning yet it is unrecognized by most posters here! I am baffled!

Answer (score 1):

The number $e$ is defined by: $e=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n!}$ but historically I think that the definition of the $exp$ function is: $e^x=\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$ and the properties of this function comes from this definition as shown in this [article](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VKWHjd3zqtRTdvM0RNYmhsOTg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Not correct. Historically, $e^x$ was defined at first as infinite power series. Limits come only in the second half of XIXc.

Comment: @user48672 I just edited the link to the article. You can now have access to it. Also, see this:

http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/e.html

In the 6th paragraph, we see that the limit concept was already present in 1683. The definition $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$ comes in 1748.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the computation of the derivative of the general $y= a^x$ where a can be any positive number.
$y(x+ h)- y(x)= a^{x+ h}- a^x= (a^x)(a^h)- a^x= a^x(a^h- 1)$
So $\frac{y(x+h)- y(x)}{h}= a^x\left(\frac{a^h- 1}{h}\right)$

$\frac{da^x}{dx}= \lim_{h\to 0}a^x\left(\frac{a^h- 1}{h}\right)$
$= a^x\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{a^h- 1}{h}\right)$

So the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x$ times some constant, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h- 1}{h}$.

It is easy to see that, if a= 1, since $a^h= 1$ for all x, that limit is 0 and if a= 3, since $3^{0.001}= 1.001099$,  approximately, $\frac{1.01099- 1}{0.001}= 1.099$, there is some a, between 1 and 3, such that $\
lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^{x+h}- a^x}{h}= 1$.

We define "e" to be that value of a so that the derivative  of $e^x$ is 1 times $e^x$.