# Sum of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \rho^{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I encounter the infinite series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k \rho^{k-1}$ in a math textbook where the answer is directly given to be $\dfrac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}$ when $|\rho| < 1$. However, I don't understand how to obtain this result. Could someone give me a hint of how to approach this problem?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Think of the convergent series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \rho^k=\frac{1}{1-\rho}, \qquad |\rho|<1,$$ and differentiate both sides with respect to $\rho$ (why is interchanging differentiation and summation possible?).

Comment: I looked at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147869/interchanging-the-order-of-differentiation-and-summation) and understand now why we can interchange differentiation and summation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Start off with the geometric sum$$\frac 1{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}c^n$$Now differentiate it with respect to $x$ to get$$\frac 1{(1-x)^2}=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}n x^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with the formula and derivation of the geometric series, then you can justify this by showing you can pass derivatives into a series inside the radius of convergence. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484250/is-there-a-simple-proof-that-a-power-series-can-be-differentiated-term-by-term/484280) contains a good rundown of why what we are about to do is valid.

Recall the following:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} \quad \text{when } |x|<1
$$
If you differentiate both sides you find the following:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \quad \text{when } |x|<1
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method which avoids use of derivatives or integrals. Let $S$ be the sum of the series. By distributing $\rho$ among the summands of your series, show that $\rho S = S - \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \rho^k$. Use the formula for the sum of a geometric series and solve for $S$ to obtain $S = \dfrac{1}{(1 - \rho)^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an arithmetic-geometric series. One term $(k)$ is in arithmetic progression, while the other $(\rho^{k-1})$ is in geometric progression. It converges for $|\rho|<1$. You can find the value like this:

$\displaystyle S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\rho^{k-1}=1+2\rho+3\rho^2+4\rho^3...$

$\displaystyle\rho S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\rho^k=\rho+2\rho^2+3\rho^3+4\rho^4...$

$\displaystyle (1-\rho)S=1+\rho+\rho^2...=\frac1{1-\rho}$ for $|\rho|<1$

$\displaystyle\therefore S=\frac1{(1-\rho)^2}$